Is there a possesive form of "here" or "there"?
Imagine your house has just been cleaned by a helper. So after the cleaning finished, you check around if everthing was placed properly, and you see that a mat or (a piece of rug) that you normally use in the living room was mistakenly placed in another room.
Can I say it this way (pointing my finger at the rug):
It is not here's. It is the living room's. (as in the case of "It is not mine, it is hers.")

No. It's not grammatical, and the sentence doesn't make sense. There is no possessive form of here or there.  It would be more natural to say something like.: "This [rug] should be in the living room." or perhaps "This [rug] goes in the living room".

It's the living room's. OK for it belongs in the living room.

You could say

Here's [here is] where it goes.
It goes here.
It belongs here.

The last, with "belongs", is the closest you can get to the notion of possessive.

Very good answer thanks. So, can I say: "Here is not where it goes. There is where it goes."

Putting "here" and "there" at the beginning like that puts great emphasis on them. Such emphasis could convey frustration or anger. So yes, you can say that if you are giving a reprimand: this is not the first time the person has put something in the wrong place. The person keeps putting it in the wrong place again and again despite being instructed otherwise.

it is always good to learn. We were taught at school that "Here is ....." is used when you are giving something to someone, e.g "Here is your key." Now I have understood that the same structure is also used for giving a reprimand. Makes sense because you are still giving something :)

@Yunus:   What suggests it a reprimand is specific to the situation, the word order, and the mirroring of the two clauses:  Here is not where it goes. There is where it goes.   This could be perfectly neutral:  Here is where we keep the presta valves.

@Yunus Also, the negative in the first sentence suggests reprimand.  Here is not where it goes.
